# Visual Studio 2015 intellisense not appearing during debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

When I use a watch I get this error message:

```
Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.
```

It's really strange because I can only get intellisense in some parts of the application. The issue originally started when I couldn't step into my methods, so through searching. I turned off the just my code option in the debugger.

So far I have tried:

1. Restart machine
2. Clean + Rebuild VS2015
3. I have turned off all optimisations for debugging

I have no idea what to do. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

Code where it happens:

```
 public IList<string> PopulateFilterList(string selectedFields) {
            IList<string> ExcludedFields = _homeRepository.GetExcludedFields();
            Type t = typeof(Invoice);

            return null;
        }
```

I'm just trying to look at `t`

Edit: If I check the option 'Suppress JIT optimisation on module load' in the debugger I get intellisense. I get intellisense

Comment: You have turned of all optimisations for debugging, but are you in the Debug solution configuration?

Comment: Can you show some code where the behaviour is happening?

Comment: I barely remember something like that happening to me once, but i think that it got solved with a clean + rebuild. Anyway try to delete the /bin and /obj contents and see if that helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VS 2015 Community Edition

go to Debug->Options or Tools->Options

and check Debugging->General->Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)

if this doesn't work check that all projects in the solution have the option "Optimize code" un-ticked in the project properties.